# error insecure configuration in radiusd.conf file and raddb dictionary (freeradius server)

Tags: debugging, configuration, radius

command:

> radiusd -X

output:

```
radiusd: FreeRADIUS Version 3.0.1, for host i686-pc-linux-gnu, built on Sep 23 2014 at    00:27:30  
Copyright (C) 1999-2014 The FreeRADIUS server project and contributors
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE
You may redistribute copies of FreeRADIUS under the terms of the
GNU General Public License
For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYRIGHT
Starting - reading configuration files ...
including dictionary file /usr/local/etc/raddb/dictionary
including configuration file /usr/local/etc/raddb/radiusd.conf
Configuration file /usr/local/etc/raddb/radiusd.conf is globally writable.Refusing   to   start due to insecure configuration.
Errors reading or parsing /usr/local/etc/raddb/radiusd.conf
```

the output states that insecure configuration by observing output.could anyone know,why it is happend, please give me your remedies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've changed the permissions of radiusd.conf using something like `chmod g+w`. `chmod g-w /usr/local/etc/raddb/radiusd.conf` to fix it.

Comment: thanks for info,i had changed dictionary,clients.conf,radiusd.conf,proxy.conf permissions for only to user mode,that is the why i get my freeradius server is running without disturbance. thanks to @Arran Cudbard-Bell